# Not able to fetch ip address of pods using Kubectl and jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

I'm trying to get the ip address of pods with particular label using jsonpath with the following command:

`kubectl get pods -l app=validate -n {namespace_name} -o jsonpath={.status.podIP}`

But this doesn't result into anything, even though the namespace and label names are correct. On the other hand, if I try to do:

`kubectl get pod/pod_name -n {namespace_name} -o jsonpath={.status.podIP}`

I'm able to get the pod IP address after that. But the problem is, since I'm trying to query all the pods created for a particular deployment, I want to fetch Ip addresses for all the pods under that particular label. I'm not sure what is wrong with the command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have multiple Pods with the same label, you get a list of Pods. You have to adjust your jsonpath to  `-o jsonpath="{.items[*].status.podIP}"` to get all the podIPs.

Comment: or this if you also need name

`k get pods -A -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.status.podIP}{" "}{@.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns), you can add custom columns when querying a list of resources.

So you can do `kubectl get pods -l app=validate -n {namespace_name} -o custom-columns=ip:.status.podIP`